# Define variables in a template of steps of azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a template of steps that I reuse in a pipeline.
This is my template of steps (template.yaml) in the repo devops:

```
steps: 
- script: make build 
  workingDirectory: $(Build.Repository.Name) 
  displayName: 'Build'
```

This is my pipeline (pipeline.yaml)

```
trigger: 
  branches: 
    include: 
    - feature/* 
  paths: 
    include: 
    - app/* 
pool: 
  vmImage: ubuntu-22.04 
resources: 
  repositories: 
  - repository: devops 
    type: git 
    name: devops 
    ref: master 

variables: 
- group: DevSecOps.POC 

steps: 
- checkout: self 
- checkout: devops 

- bash: mv devops/ ${BUILD_REPOSITORY_NAME}/.scripts/ 
  displayName: dir 

- template: pipelines/template.yaml@devops
```

Is it possible to put the variables in the template.yaml file?

```
variables: 
- group: DevSecOps.POC

steps: 
- script: make build 
  workingDirectory: $(Build.Repository.Name) 
  displayName: 'Build'
```

I get this error: `Unexpected value 'variables'` when I try to run the pipeline

Comment: As mentioned below variable blocks  are not compatible at the steps level. Are you trying to figure out how to pass the variable group values to the `template.yml` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because "steps" isn't a valid scope at which a `variables` block can exist. Variables can be defined in a job, or in a stage, or at the root of the template.

In short, you're already defining the variables when you import the variable group at the `job` scope.